# RFID-RC522 unable to detect some tags but correctly reads others

Tags: rfid

I'm trying to read an NFC/RFID tag using Arduino and an RFID-RC522 module.
Currently I'm able to successfully read the data from a key fob and from a card that were included with the RC522, but the tag I want to read is not detected at all.
Is the module I'm using unsuitable to read this kind of tags?

Tag:

[image]

Code:

```cpp
    #include <SPI.h>
    #include <MFRC522.h>
    
    #define SS_PIN 10
    #define RST_PIN 9
    
    MFRC522 rfid(SS_PIN, RST_PIN);
    
    void setup() {
      Serial.begin(9600);
      SPI.begin(); // init SPI bus
      rfid.PCD_Init(); // init MFRC522
    
      Serial.println("Tag reader on");
    }
    
    void loop() {
      if (rfid.PICC_IsNewCardPresent()) { // new tag is available
        if (rfid.PICC_ReadCardSerial()) { // NUID has been readed
          MFRC522::PICC_Type piccType = rfid.PICC_GetType(rfid.uid.sak);
          Serial.print("RFID/NFC Tag Type: ");
          Serial.println(rfid.PICC_GetTypeName(piccType));
    
          // print NUID in Serial Monitor in the hex format
          Serial.print("UID:");
          for (int i = 0; i < rfid.uid.size; i++) {
            Serial.print(rfid.uid.uidByte[i] < 0x10 ? " 0" : " ");
            Serial.print(rfid.uid.uidByte[i], HEX);
          }
          Serial.println();
    
          rfid.PICC_HaltA(); // halt PICC
          rfid.PCD_StopCrypto1(); // stop encryption on PCD
        }
      }
    }
```

Output read on Serial Monitor when I scan the key fob and the card:

```
Tag reader on
RFID/NFC Tag Type: MIFARE 1KB
UID: BC 38 B4 12
RFID/NFC Tag Type: MIFARE 1KB
UID: 86 FB 35 B6
```

Wiring:

[image]

My RC522 module:

[image]

Comment: seems that way .

Comment: `the tag I want to read is not detected at all` - what tag, *exactly*?

Comment: Did you see on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio-frequency_identification that there are multiple frequencies in use? The RC522 knows only 13,56 MHz...

Comment: @NickGammon the flat round one in the picture.

Comment: I was hoping for a part number, not a picture of some coils. As the busybee said, different RFID cards operate at different frequencies.

Comment: @NickGammon I see, thank you. Unfortunately I don't know the specification of the tag. It's on the package of consumable goods, whose production is now discontinued. These tags used to be read by a cooking device. Would you suggest me to try another RFID module according to the shape of the tag? Which one?

Comment: I did a Google Lens search of that image, and some results appear to suggest it is a 13.56 MHz tag, however I didn't see *exactly* a match on your image. Possibly another RFID module would work, or possibly that tag has failed. Those tags have a small microprocessor on them, conceivably it has gone bad.

Comment: @NickGammon thank you so much for your valuable help. If so, I should be able to read it (if the tag itself is not faulty). I suspect I may be affected by [this issue](https://www.eluke.nl/2018/03/08/fixed-rc522-rfid-reader-not-reading-some-cards-part-1/).

Comment: Quite possibly. I buy stuff from eBay, and it often works, but I also wonder if I am dealing with seconds. You know, stuff the manufacturer discarded because it didn't work properly.